# "firebase.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system" when I try to firebase init from vs code

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

firebase : File C:\Users\WALTON\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts
is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- firebase init
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```